# CSS font family only apply to certain elements within the same class

Tags: html, css

I have made a simple todo list where i am able to append a new item into the existing list each time user input and press enter.

I wanted to change the font and i apply my font-family into Body tag. However it ONLY applies to my existing element, but not the new elements that have been added.

```js
$("input").on("keypress", function(e) {
  var newToDo = $(this).val();
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $("ul").append('<li><span><i class="fa fa-bomb" aria-hidden="true"> ' + newToDo + '</li>');
    $(this).val("");
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

body {
  background: #36D1DC;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div id="container">

  <h1>TO DO LIST <i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
  <input placeholder="Add New Todo" />
  <ul>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-bomb" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> TEST 1</li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-bomb" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> TEST 2</li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-bomb" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> TEST 3</li>
  </ul>


</div>
```

Questions: 
 1. Why new entry created by the user input is using DIFFERENT font although i am trying to use same font through BODY TAG.

POC that i have tried: 
 1. Make sure there is no overriden, by assigning same font on all css. 
 E.g. All classes, ID will have "font-family: Roboto;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly then it might be because haven't setup the `append` properly as it is missing some closing html tags (the closing `i` and `span`).  Update that line to be:

```
$("ul").append('<li><span><i class="fa fa-bomb" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> ' + newToDo + '</li>');
```

I think (without a code demo) as you are not closing the `i` it is wrapping the font applied to Font Awesome to your text that the user inputted

Comment: Good spotting—also emphasises why it is important for OP to actually include a proof-of-concept example instead of just a code dump in the answer, where it is way easier to diagnose the actual problem.

Comment: @Deanmv i was thinking it could be another thing that has overridden my font type and overlook that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Terry thank you for the advice, i have remove unnecessary code so that my question can be more concise for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial list items have their text ("Test 1") outside of the `<i>` element.

When you insert an item though you're missing the closing `</i>` and `</span>` tags, so the text is considered to be inside the `<i>` and it's font is set by the .fa rule in `font-awesome.css`.